# ValidationError: empresas validation failed: county: Path `county` is required

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Não consigo ver o erro que impede de fazer o ***POST*** (guardar os dados no banco). Além disso, no formulário quando selecciono um país ele devia pegar somente as suas cidades, invés disso ele chama todas cidades e consequentemente todos os municípios. Quem tiver alguma ideia, ajude por favor! Grato.

**Modelo:**

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const Empresa = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    slug: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    county: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "coutries",
        required: true
    },
    city: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "cities",
        required: true
    },
    municipality: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "municipalities",
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    }
})

mongoose.model("empresas", Empresa)
```

**Routa / GET:**

```js
router.get('/empresas/add', async function(req, res) {
    try {
      const [countries, cities, municipalities] = await Promise.all([Country.find(), City.find(), Municipality.find()]);
      res.render('ferramentas/addempresas', { countries: countries, cities: cities, municipalities: municipalities});
    } catch(err) {
      req.flash('error_msg', 'Houve um erro ao carregar o formulário');
      res.redirect('/ferramentas/empresas');
    };
});
```

**Routa / POST:**

```js
router.post("/empresas/nova", function(req, res){

    var erros = []

    if(!req.body.name || typeof req.body.name == undefined || req.body.name == null){
        erros.push({texto: "Nome inválido"})
    }
    if(!req.body.slug || typeof req.body.slug == undefined || req.body.slug == null){
        erros.push({texto: "slug inválido"})
    }
    if(req.body.country == "0"){
        erros.push({texto: "País inválido, crie um país"})
    }
    if(req.body.city == "0"){
        erros.push({texto: "Cidade inválida, crie uma cidade"})
    }
    if(req.body.municipality == "0"){
        erros.push({texto: "Município inválido, crie antes um município"})
    }
    if(erros.length > 0){
        res.render("ferramentas/empresas", {erros: erros})
    }else{
        const novaEmpresa = {
            name: req.body.name,
            slug: req.body.slug,
            country: req.body.country,
            city: req.body.city,
            municipality: req.body.municipality
        }
        new Empresa(novaEmpresa).save().then(function(){
            req.flash("sucesso_msg", "Empresa criada com sucesso!")
            res.redirect("/ferramentas/empresas")
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log(err)
            req.flash("error_msg", "Houve um erro ao salvar a empresas, tente novamente!")
            res.redirect("/ferramentas/empresas")
        })
    }
})
```

HTML:

```html
<form action="/ferramentas/empresas/nova" method="POST">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <h6 class="card-inside-title">Nome:</h6>
    <div class="row clearfix">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Escreva o nome do município" autocomplete="off" required/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h6 class="card-inside-title">Slug:</h6>
    <div class="row clearfix">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" id="slug" name="slug" class="form-control" placeholder="Escreva o slug da município" autocomplete="off" required />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h6 class="card-inside-title">País:</h6>
    <div class="row clearfix">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0 -18px 0 -18px">
          <select name="country" class="form-control">
            <option>Selecione o país</option>
            {{#each countries}}
            <option value="{{_id}}">{{name}}</option>
            {{else}}
            <option value="0">Sem país registrado</option>
            {{/each}}
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h6 class="card-inside-title">Cidade:</h6>
    <div class="row clearfix">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0 -18px 0 -18px">
          <select name="city" class="form-control">
            <option>Selecione a cidade</option>
            {{#each cities}}
            <option value="{{_id}}">{{name}}</option>
            {{else}}
            <option value="0">Sem cidade registrada</option>
            {{/each}}
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h6 class="card-inside-title">Município:</h6>
    <div class="row clearfix">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0 -18px 0 -18px">
          <select name="municipality" class="form-control">
            <option>Selecione o local</option>
            {{#each municipalities}}
            <option value="{{_id}}">{{name}}</option>
            {{else}}
            <option value="0">Sem município registrado</option>
            {{/each}}
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-round waves-effect">GUARDAR</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Sua URL da rota POST é /empresas/nova e a que você está enviando o post do formulário é /ferramentas/empresas/nova são urls diferentes, coloque /ferramentas/empresas/nova na url da rota post

Comment: @Anderson, você pode usar middlewares para organizar suas rotas. Acho que é seguro deduzir que um middleware redireciona para esse módulo se "ferramentas" estiver na base da URL, não tem nada errado com a rota.

Comment: Eu sei, mas não estou vendo nenhum middleware ali

Comment: Estou usando MiddleWare, apenas não coloquei neste poste.

Answer (score -1):

Bom dia,
o problema está no seu código do Schema.
Ao invés de escrever "country" está escrito "county".

Comment: `ValidationError: empresas validation failed: county: Path "county" is required
`
Responde exatamente a este problema.